Referring to the figure. Find the polar equation.
Referring to the figure, find the polar equation of the curve representing the geometric place of all points $P$ in the plane such that $\overline{PC} = 2\overline{BC}$.

Can someone tell me how to proceed please :')
Edit:
I tried to plot the situation in polar coordinates:

And then to find $\overline{PC}$ and $2\overline{BC}$ , using the cosine theorem.
\begin{align*}
\sqrt{r_1^2+r_2^2-2r_1r_2\cos(\alpha-\alpha)} &= 2\sqrt{4R^2+r_2^2-4Rr_2\cos(0-\alpha)}\\ r_1^2+r_2^2-2r_1r_2 &= 4(4R^2+r_2^2-4Rr_2\cos(\alpha))
\end{align*}
First, am I correct on this point?
If so, how should I proceed? Solve the expression for $r_1$?

For what it's worth, virtually every MathSE posted question that I have seen, that followed this article on MathSE protocol has been upvoted rather than downvoted.  I am not necessarily advocating this protocol.  Instead, I am merely stating a fact: if you scrupulously follow the linked article, skipping/omitting nothing, you virtually guarantee a positive response.
